# Updating Bokeh source with CustomJS

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I need to figure out a way to have the source data return to its original state before CustomJS applies its logic so that CustomJS doesn't progressively work with a reduced dataset every time the user selects a choice.

```
# scripts/bokeh_optimal_clusters.py
filter_answered = checkbox_categorical_filter(src_ans)
checkbox_group.js_on_change('active', filter_answered)

# scripts/functions/bokeh_callbacks.py
def checkbox_categorical_filter(src_ans): 
 return CustomJS(...)
```

Here's the [repo](https://github.com/NeelRoshania/ml-powered-applications/tree/master/neel/scripts).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the bug [here](https://github.com/NeelRoshania/ml-powered-applications/blob/master/neel/scripts/bokeh_optimal_clusters.py).

Key is to pass all bokehs source objects to CustomJS, process the data using the original source and pass the filtered one.